# Android/Cocos2d-x unsatisfiedlinkerror using JNI using Java to call C++

Tags: android, c++, android-ndk, java-native-interface, cocos2d-x

EDIT: I've solved this problem (and found the next issue in the long line of JNI tribulations!) by changing the following:

Delete "static" declaration of the native method in both Java and C++, add a Java method to get an instance of my SimpleGame class, and calling

```
public static void callCppApiResponse (String result, String token, long context) {
**getInstance()**.cppAndroidApiResponse(token, 200, result, result.length(), context);
}
```

Now the information successfully makes it from Java to C++. Hopefully this may help someone else with a similar issue.

ORIGINAL POST:

I'm using the Cocos2d-x platform and writing C++ code for a cross-platform iOS/Android app, and there are certain methods that I need to be handled by the respective native iOs/Android systems, so I need to be able to call Java from C++ then call C++ from Java.

I am able to load the shared library for the app and trigger a Java response from C++, but when I try to call C++ from Java I get the following logcat output and the app crashes:

```
dalvik vm     No implementation found for native Lorg/cocos2dx/simplegame/SimpleGame; cppSideAndroidApiResponse:(Ljava/lang/String;ILJava/lang/String;IJ)V
AndroidRuntime      java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Native method not found: org.cocos2dx.simplegame.SimpleGame.cppAndroidApiResponse:(Ljava/lang/String;ILJava/lang/String;IJ)V
```

Here is the relevant Java code:

```
package org.cocos2dx.simplegame;

private static native void cppAndroidApiResponse(String token, int response, String data, int dataLen, long context);

static {
    System.loadLibrary("sb");
}

public static void callCppApiResponse (String result, String token, long context) {
//This is where the error is triggered
    cppAndroidApiResponse(token, 200, result, result.length(), context);
}
```

and in the C++ file cppSide.h:

```
# if (CC_TARGET_PLATFORM == CC_PLATFORM_ANDROID)
#include "platform/android/jni/JniHelper.h"
#include <jni.h>
#endif

#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif
# if (CC_TARGET_PLATFORM == CC_PLATFORM_ANDROID)
JNIEXPORT static void JNICALL 
Java_org_cocos2dx_simplegame_SimpleGame_cppAndroidApiResponse(JNIEnv *, jobject, jstring, jint, jstring, jint, jlong);
#endif
#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif
```

Then finally the cppSide.cpp file

```
#include "cppSide.h"

extern "C" {
JNIEXPORT static void JNICALL      
Java_org_cocos2dx_simplegame_SimpleGame_cppAndroidApiResponse(JNIEnv *env, jobject obj, jstring token, jint response, jstring data, jint length, jlong context)
{ ...do stuff...}
}
```

I know that my shared library is loading because I get my C++ based loading screen, and I know that JNI is working at least partially because I am able to call Java from that same cppSide.cpp file in another method. I have been researching the JNI and Cocos2d-X documentation, but to no avail.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: are you sure you have added this to the make file?

Comment: Yes thank you for the suggestion. I guess I should have the makefile up here too, but it includes every cpp file in the classes directory.